# Does Skype encrypt IP destination?

Tags: encryption, skype

Does Skype encrypt the IP destination (the IP of the people I talked to) in instant messaging?
Now Skype uses the cloud, does my ISP know the IP destination or is my message sent to the cloud?

Answer (score 4):

Since some years, all of the Skype communication happens through their servers and not directly.

There is no IP to hide (encrypt) because your Skype client doesn't know the IP of your pals.

Comment: if skype doesn't know their IP, how does it send them messages?

Comment: @dandavis They know the IPs of the servers of the Skype. They are far away, somewhere in the server centrals of the micro$oft, and you won't ever see them. All of your skype clients, your and your pals, are communicating through the skype servers, and not with each other directly.

Comment: nevermind, i somehow missed the keyword, "_client_"...

Answer (score 2):

This answer is adding to @peterh answer

Yes, Skype uses its own networking layer, to deliver messages and voice data, but also Skype provide a lot of information about contacts: there is a SQLite database in local Skype settings. Path for Linux: `$HOME/.Skype/<skypelogin>/main.db`. There is a lot of information and probably, it was sent to you through your ISP.

Moreover, there is a some kind of [SORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SORM) system in most countries; and Skype and most ISP provide an access to the user data in case of investigation of crimes.

Comment: I could not find the database. Could you please clarify more? I use windows 7. What do you mean it was sent to me through my ISP? The database?

Comment: @Moba, the DB on windows-host is here: `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Skype\skype.id` (actually, there are **several** databases), more information about this DB and a lot of other interesting info about security in Skype - [**here**](http://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/24475/hacking/skype-local-database-plaintext.html)

Comment: I did not find the file. Microsoft might have addressed this issue. The article is dated in 2014.

Comment: It was probably transmitted via a secured channel. Your ISP cannot read the main.db

Comment: @JonasDralle, good point;) **probably** — because Skype protocol is proprietary, and only limited list knows what is under the hood

Comment: microsoft isn't stupid. They should know how to transmit sensitive data.